# How can I get my router to give internet access to >1 device

Tags: wireless-networking, router, internet

I have an ongoing problem with WiFi on my home network:

All devices are able to connect to the network, however only one is able to get internet access at any given time. The one exception to the 'one-at-a-time' policy is a desktop running Windows 7, also using WiFi; this is able to connect to the internet at any time with no discernible effect on the other device's (singular) internet access.

There seems to be a pattern to the priority in which the devices are able to 'claim' the internet access:

1. A Windows phone (a Lumia)
2. A Windows 7 netbook (an Asus)
3. A MacBook Air
4. An Android phone (an LG)

The router itself is a basic model provided by my ISP, specifically [a ZyXEL AMG1202-T10A](ftp://ftp.zyxel.com/AMG1202-T10A/user_guide/AMG1202-T10A_.pdf). I'm not using the ethernet ports at all.

In trying to fix this myself I have determined:

- The router is acting as a DHCP server and is correctly assigning unique IP addresses to each device
- QoS is not enabled
- It is b/g/n enabled
- The logs don't seem to show anything relevant but do give firewall messages with a very high frequency. Such as:

  ```
  5/17/2015 16:8:0> Firewall: Filter no listen TCP packet! 
  5/17/2015 16:8:4> Configuration Change!
  5/17/2015 16:9:27> Firewall: Filter no port UDP packet!
  5/17/2015 16:9:29> Last errorlog repeat 4 Times
  5/17/2015 16:9:31> Firewall: Filter no port UDP packet!
  5/17/2015 16:9:46> Last errorlog repeat 7 Times
  5/17/2015 16:9:47> Firewall: Filter no port UDP packet!
  ```

Any suggestions at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Try enabling QoS & WMM

Comment: I've looked into enabling QoS but as it doesn't seem that my problems have arisen from using any particular application or amount of bandwidth; just the number of devices. QoS is about giving applications priorities for bandwidth, not devices... is that right?

Comment: ports & protocols, rather than applications, but it's rare QoS & WMM will make things worse; they're reasonably smart these days

Comment: This is all about WiFi, right? And the Windows 7 desktop is also using WiFi, or is it using ethernet, or both? Anything in the router's logs? (Page 193 of [the manual](ftp://ftp.zyxel.com/AMG1202-T10A/user_guide/AMG1202-T10A_.pdf#page=193).) And any chance a reset of the modem would work...? (Page 25. Of course, if it helps, then we'll all be left wondering what setting caused this...)

Comment: I'll give QoS a try then, the QoS settings page suggests it's entirely dependent on manually assigned rules rather than a simple on/off box.

Comment: Arjan - the logs don't seem to show anything relevant but do give firewall messages with a very high frequency. Such as:

5/17/2015 16:8:0> Firewall: Filter no listen TCP packet!
5/17/2015 16:8:4> Configuration Change!
5/17/2015 16:9:27> Firewall: Filter no port UDP packet!
5/17/2015 16:9:29> Last errorlog repeat 4 Times
5/17/2015 16:9:31> Firewall: Filter no port UDP packet!
5/17/2015 16:9:46> Last errorlog repeat 7 Times
5/17/2015 16:9:47> Firewall: Filter no port UDP packet!

I've tried hard resets to no avail, I'll have a look at page 25 now though.

Comment: The desktop is just on the wifi, it's never touched the router via an ethernet cable.

Comment: Any luck when using only *one* WiFi standard, like just 802.11b for a quick test? (I assume a router should support multiple *simultaneously*, but I am actually not sure.) (And I assume that the `Configuration Change!` is caused by yourself, not by some UPnP triggered by a device...?)

Comment: And just in case you're in doubt if all devices are *really* on the local network: on the Mac you can run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in Terminal, and then on the other devices open a browser to go to the Mac's IP address, on port 8000...

Comment: @Arjan Thank you!
I changed the channel to 802.11b, all the devices can now access the internet. Same for 'g'. To switch to 'n' for higher potential speed the router prompted me to change the encryption from TKIP to AES. After doing this the desktop stopped being able to connect to the network at all; looking at the desktop's usb wireless antennae it says "802.11g - 54 Mbps" (can an 802.11g even attain 54Mbps?). So settled on the 802.11g channel until I can upgrade my desktop's antennae, and problem solved!

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for your help as well. Now that I'll be able to finally get multiple devices online I'll set up the QoS so I'll be able to make the most of Netflix, Xbox Live etc. without making all of this effort redundant. There doesn't seem to be any reference to WMM within my router's settings though? Are there brand-related symonyms, or could my router just be out of date?

Comment: WMM is 'part' of QoS, but specifically for voice/media streaming. It might be rolled into one option on a newer router, or not present on an older one. BTW, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_security#Security_measures for the bewildering varieties of wifi encryption ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Following Arjan's advice, altering the settings within the router from an 802.11 b/g/n channel to a single form of the aformentioned channels (b OR g OR n) allowed all devices to gain access to the internet.

Two things to note are that the singular 802.11 n channel was dysfunctional with TKIP as opposed to AES encryption; also an older usb wifi antennae was unable to connect to the 802.11 n frequency network.

Comment: If anyone knows if proper routers should support multiple protocols simultaneously, I'd love to know. (I never had any problems with using a combined b/g/n setting, but maybe routers then fall back to the protocol supported by all connected devices?)